# Problems with casted generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I read every previous post I found asking this question, but none of them I could make applicable to what I am doing for this assignment.  To start, I have to use an array.  Second, the class containing the generic array is being accessed and used by other classes.  So while I can compile something like:

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[15];
```

When I try to run any other classes that use this data structure, I get the error that they can't be cast.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; can
not be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

The solutions or workarounds I read mostly had using Array.newInstance() to create the class and cast it as generic type T[].  The issue that I am running into is that I do not know what class I would use with this method.  Nothing is passed to my constructor.

My initial workaround was instantiate the array as a string and cast to T[].  This worked and my class compiled and my little driver executed perfectly.  But now I am writing another class that uses a new data structure that is then fed into this data structure.  It breaks when I try to add anything into the array.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: DATATYPE
```

The error gives me the line that is when I try to add this to the array in its original class:

```
store[length] = item;
```

item is passed to the add method as

```
T item
```

Is there something that I am missing here?  I thought I would be able to cast it as T[] and then fill it with generic items T.

Edit:  This is the relevant portion of the add method and class:

```
public class AThreadedBSTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements        
    ThreadedBSTreeInterface<T>, Cloneable
{

    public void add(T item)
    {
          ensureCapacity();

          store[length] = item;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to test the add method with different data structures:

```
 public class Driver 
 {
      public static void main(String args[]) 
      {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Datatype test = new Datatype(in);
            AThreadedBSTree<Datatype> tree = new AThreadedBSTree<Datatype>();
            tree.add(test);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the method from where u r using it

Comment: Please post the full generic method, the way you call it, and the example data you used to get such an exception. In other words, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: "Do not use `Object[]` but `T[]`" - where would that start to hurt. Show us that spot, and there might rise some solutions, like the aforementioned Array, and Arrays.

Comment: Sorry.  Added some code, let me know if there is more.  Really frustrated because I thought I was pretty much done with this assignment and now I can't do the last part which is the easiest.

Comment: Really, the simplest approach would be just using ArrayList<T>, which does the necessary casting for you.

Comment: This is probably another homework; they have to use array and rape the language because the teacher has an inclination to teach syntax instead of programming. Sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
 T[] store = (T[]) Array.newInstance(Comparable.class, size);
```

for your backing array instead of using an `Object` array. This will not produce the `ClassCastException` you are experiencing. It should also not produce any `ArrayStoreException` as far as I can tell (at least I am not getting any in my small test).

Of course it would be nicer to create an array of `T`, but the only way to do that is to get a reference to `Class<T>` (perhaps through a constructor argument) and use that in `Array.newInstance(...)`.

Comment: When attempting to try this, I got an error.
     _error: cannot find symbol
   store =(T[]) Array.newInstance(Comparable.class, 12);
                ^
  symbol:   variable Array_

Comment: Did you import the `Array` class properly? It is located at `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

Comment: I thought I had but I guess not.  Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to add, for anyone in the future who is looking this up, the reason that this answer helped me when the thousands of other questions that are pretty much the same as mine couldn't, was because of the Comparable.class.  My main problem was I didn't know what class I should use when using Array.newInstance.  This works perfectly for creating a workaround generic array.

Comment: As Chamly Idunil pointed out, you can use just `T[] store = (T[]) new Comparable[size];`. That is probably a better idea.

Comment: There is never a point to use `Array.newInstance()` with a class literal. Just use `new Comparable[size]`

Comment: Yeah, I rarely deal with object arrays. Forgot that you can create arrays of interfaces without reflection hackage...

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement Comparable on Driver class.

```
public class Driver implements Comparable<Driver>
```

and use this for initialize array.

```
T[] arr = (T[]) new Comparable[15];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code which acheive the same ends as a cast of an array:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public <T> T[] cast(Object[] array, Class<T> type)
{
  T[] castArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, array.length);

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    castArray[i] = (T)array[i];
  }

  return castArray;
}
```

You'll obviously need to be careful as it's easy to get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` but then you'd expect that even if you could cast the original array directly.